# Missing Logo in Repository

Tags: repository, plugin-repository

I experience a quite odd behavior of the WordPress Repository, or I am doing something wrong (more likely).

So, for my plugin, which is registered in the WordPress Repository, I created a logo and I uploaded it as `icon-128x128.png` as well as `icon-256x256.png` in the `/assets/`-folder.

First I only uploaded the small logo and it didn't show up in the search results. I thought, I wait a bit, since the Repository needs sometimes a bit time to react. After this logo didn't show up, I've decided maybe I should also upload the bigger 256px logo. So I did.

Since then, the logo shows up in the search results of the WordPress admin. But it doesn't show up in the search results on wordpress.org. Moreover, also the default icon, which usually shows up, when no logo is uploaded, doesn't show.

[image: Logo shows up in admin but not on wordpress.org]

When I look into the CSS of wordpress.org I find the following:

```
#plugin-icon-filter-custom-fields-taxonomies-light {
    background-image: url("");
    background-size: 128px 128px;
    height: 128px;
    width: 128px;
}
```

Usually, the logo should be placed as a `background-image`.

Has anyone an idea, whats going on? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing how your plugin is diplayed with your neighbour on the list here [https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=custom+fields+taxonomies+light](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=custom%20fields%20taxonomies%20light), they have 2 images on the CSS inline script, and yours only show one, the other background image  url being empty.

Yours:

```
background-image: url(//ps.w.org/filter-custom-fields-taxonomies-light/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1110269
background-image: url()
```

Theirs:

```
background-image: url(//ps.w.org/advanced-custom-fields/assets/icon-128x128.png?rev=1082746
background-image: url(//ps.w.org/advanced-custom-fields/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1082746
```

If you are sure you uploaded that 128px image, in the right format and extension, it may be corrupt? Is not saved on the server properly? Maybe you will have to delete and upload it again?

The image 
`http://ps.w.org/filter-custom-fields-taxonomies-light/assets/icon-128x128.png?rev=1110269` 
is not found on the server whereas 
`http://ps.w.org/filter-custom-fields-taxonomies-light/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1110269` 
is, therefore the 128px picture is not on the server...

**EDIT:**

Here http://ps.w.org/filter-custom-fields-taxonomies-light/assets/ we can see that your 128x128 image is written not with an `x` but something else very similar, a `×` that becomes icon-128%c3%97128.png  instead of icon-128x128.png!

Comment: %c3%97 is in fact a multiplication sign :-) http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: genius! thanks a lot. i have no idea how i did this XD